# Is there a free Oracle database emulator?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I need to test certain Oracle 11g queries in order to get some real practical experience, for instance, this query:

```
select TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('01-JAN-00', 'DD-MON-RR'), 'Day') from dual;
```

in order to be 100% that it returns 'One' and not the day of week, such as Monday, etc., and other such queries.

Is there an online free Oracle database emulator?

Thank you for assistance.

Comment: Just download oracleXE.  ALL of oracle is free to download, you only need and account, which is free.  Then you can execute any query using their free development tool, sqlDeveloper.

Comment: Thank you. I did not know there was a free version of Oracle 11g. I have just downloaded it and will try it.

Answer (score 3):

test it with [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/)
your query return `Saturday`, change the `Day` to `D` to get the day number of week:

```
select TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('01-JAN-00', 'DD-MON-RR'), 'D') from dual;
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4dc72f/2)

**EDIT:** and if you want to get `the day number in month` try this (use `dd`):

```
SELECT to_char(TO_DATE('01-JAN-00', 'DD-MON-RR'),'dd') FROM DUAL
```

Comment: Thank you! It is a cool tool. But how do I execute the code? There seems to be no buttons or help prompts.

Comment: you are welcome, just choose your RDBMS as oracle, you also need to build your schema, just create a test table to be able to execute your code, see the DEMO link in my answer

Answer (score 2):

All versions of Oracle are free to download and learn on. The tricky part comes in as soon as your Oracle installation becomes involved in moving code into production. At that point, you need to licensing your Oracle install.

If you want support, Oracle Personal Edition is not terribly expensive.